# How to identify mac users's LastLogon in active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I am junior sys admin perviously I was a computer programmer and I am assigned a task, clean up active directory.

I am advised by my supervisor that LastLogon is not the true indicator to disable or delete users because last logon time doesn't change for mac users.

Is it true? is there a turn on/off feature to log LastLogon for mac users? basically i want to disable users who hasn't logged in last 180 days. There all types of users in the network i.e. linux Windows Mac.

Answer (score 1):

LastLogon should not be used because it is not replicated to other domain controllers. LastLogonTimestamp is the attribute to use. And the endpoint type does not matter.

Comment: I will use LastLogonTimestamp.
Greg, If I get you right you are saying that regardless of endpoint type (type of operating system that user is using) active directory would record LastLogonTimestamp correctly (LastlogonTimestamp updates in active directory for every successful log in attempt)